# Spark SQL between statement

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How to find the salary within a range? Here is my Spark SQL dataframe code for finding the salary between 10000 and 20000:

```
empData.where($"Salary" > 10000 && $"Salary" < 20000).orderBy($"Salary".desc).show()
```

I believe there should be an alternative solution using `between`. How can I use `between` approach?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I believe have alternative solution to use between.

Just like that:

```
empData.where($"Salary".between(10000, 20000))
```

Comment: Actually this is slightly incorrect as the 'between' function is inclusive: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column@between(lowerBound:Any,upperBound:Any):org.apache.spark.sql.Column

Comment: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#between(lowerBound:Any,upperBound:Any):org.apache.spark.sql.Column

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to use between, you can use sparkSQL and run logic as query. For e.g.

```
empData.createOrReplaceTempView("empDataTempTable")

val filteredData = spark.sql("select * from empDataTempTable where salary between 10000 and 20000 order by salary desc")

 filteredData.show()
```

For random lookups in a column and filter process, sparkSQL and DataFrame gives almost same performance results.

Answer (score 0):

```
empData.filter(col("Salary").between(10000 ,20000)).orderBy(col("Salary").desc());
```

or

```
empData.where(col("Salary").between(10000 ,20000)).orderBy(col("Salary").desc());
```